# Windows service does not recognize network path. Whats the workaround?

Tags: c++, windows, service, backup, share

We have a Buffalo NAS drive as a backup drive.

And when we map this drive as `B:\` , our backup application seems to understand this and run as an application.

But when run as a service, it does not recognize the mapping and crashes.

I tried giving the path as `\\\192.168.x.x\Backups\` as the backup path, the service runs but then a lot of submodules fail because it sees the `\\\` as a escape character.

What is the workaround so that the windows service can see the mapped drive.

I am trying to run zip.exe via a `CreateProcess()`;

`""C:\Users\jvenkatraj\Documents\SQLite\Debug\zip.exe" -9 -q -g -u "\\\192.168.123.60\Backup\store\location1\50\f2\25\43\d8\88\b9\68\49\8d\2b\d0\08\9e\7e\df\z.zip" "\\\192.168.123.60\Backup\store\temp\SPD405.tmp\file_contents""`

The backslashes are messing with the quotes. And it is a WCHAR type, and I can't change it to any other type, else I will have to redefine this elsewhere as well. How many backslashes should I use?

Comment: Note, you have to specify your UNC path by prepending two backslashes: \\192.168.x.x\Backups.

Comment: I had added two backslahes in the question, but after I posted it, it shows only one. Let me update my question

Comment: To clarify, is the backup application that is installed as a system service your own code, or a third party application?  Is it this application that is calling CreateProcess on zip.exe?

Comment: Yes, this service is a code  written in c++, and it tries to run the command via CreateProcess on zip.exe.  Because of the many double quotes, the UNC path is not being recognized. I tried it with 3,4,5,6 backslahes and it is not working.

Comment: I've made another suggestion below, but if you want to fix the CreateProcess issue, I'd recommend that you pop up a message box before calling CreateProcess so that you can see exactly what string is actually being passed to zip.exe.  It may just be a matter of getting the backslashes in the right places.

Comment: Hey Harry, the string that I am passing to CreateProcess is mentioned in the question above.

Comment: That's the string you think you are passing, but have you confirmed it, i.e., by outputting it to a message box or text file?  It also looks to me as if the web site is munging it, do you really have three backslashes at the beginning of the paths?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. It needed 8 backslashes. Since each backslash escapes the other. The string would need to appear like it had 4 backslashes, now it works. Thanks a lot Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map a network drive inside the service itself using the WNetAddConnection2 API function.

Answer (score 1):

Create a symbolic link somewhere to the NAS share:

```
mklink /D c:\nas-backups \\192.168.x.x\Backups
```

and point your backup application to `c:\nas-backups\etc`.

Comment: this is great. Can you tell me how to make it work on XP and 2003?

Comment: Oops.  Sorry, Symbolic Links were introduced with Vista/WS2008.  They're not available on XP and 2003.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to access the network path

```
string path = @"\\192.168.x.x\Backups\";
```

Another thing you have to make sure of is that the service has access to this path.  If your service is logged in as a user that does NOT have access you have to change logon credentials of the service to a user/domain account that does have access to this path.

Comment: You have it backwards - mapped drives are per-session, so services can't use users' mapped drives. Services can use UNC paths just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your service under a user that "sees" the network, such as the "Network Service" user or even as the "human" user that mapped the network drive.